# Same condition checked more time consecutively

Tags: java, if-statement

I have to assign the result of an operation (a db query or a computation) to a return variable, and eventually perform another operation if the result is not valid (null, empty, ...); however, this pattern happen at least a couple of time, and it seems a code smell to me. Should I refactor it in any way?

```
String result = planA();
if(!isValid(result))
    result = planB();
if(!isValid(result))
    result = planC();
if(!isValid(result))
    result = planD();
return result;
```

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: There is no straight answer. It really depends on the functions `planA/B/C/D` and `isValid`. Add them here, it should give us more details

Answer (score 7):

You could factor out that as a function that returns the first valid result since that is that you actually do.

In fact, in terms of expected behavior, your current code could be written like :

```
String result = planA();
if(isValid(result))
    return planB();
if(isValid(result))
    return  planC();
if(isValid(result))
    return  planD();
return result;
```

You can factor out that with a function :

```
public String computeResult(Supplier<String>... functions){
    String result = null;
    for (Supplier<String> function : functions){
       result = function.get();
       if (isValid(result)){
            return result;
       }
    }
    return result;    
}
```

And call that :

```
computeResult(this::planA, this::planB, this::planC, this::planD, ()-> this.planE(anyParam));
```

As alternative you could replace the loop by a stream in the function :

```
public String computeResult(Supplier<String>... functions){
    return 
    Arrays.stream(functions)
          .filter(s-> isValid(s.get()))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(functions.get(function.length-1)); 
          // if no valid return the last result function as in the initial code
}
```

Comment: note this works only if signatures of plan methods are same

Comment: i guess OP really should have used if and else if clauses rather than just ifs

Comment: @Sikorski Not really since you can use any method with any parameter in the body of the `Runnable` or `Supplier` passed while it returns a `String`.  For example that is valid `()-> this.planE(anyParam)`. `Supplier.get()`/`Callable.call()` invocations execute the body provided and returns the result.

Comment: @Sikorski Agreed about using `if-else if` would male more sense in the code that OP posted while I prefer the early exit idiom to not read more code than I really need to read.

Comment: @davidxxx Your solutions seems to be pretty clever; however, unluckily, I need a java 7 solution. Thank you very much anyway

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, planD is the default case if all previous checks failed. I would write it like this

```
return Stream.of(planA(),planB(),planC())
            .dropWhile(s->!isValid(s))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(planD());
```

Comment: That is an interesting Java 9 solution but you eagerly execute `planA(), planB() and planC()`. What do you think of `return Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(this::planA, this::planB, this::planC,)
.dropWhile(s -> !isValid(s.get())).findFirst().orElse(planD());`

Comment: @davidxxx I honestly haven't given much thought to the eager execution. I look at your approach with a concrete example when I have the opportunity to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a util class that can be used by anyone for any purpose:

```
public static <T> T computeWithFallbacks(Predicate<T> validityPredicate, Supplier<T>... suppliers) {
    T result = null;

    for (Supplier<T> supplier : suppliers) {
      result = supplier.get();
      if (validityPredicate.test(result)) {
        return result;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
```

This way you can provide the validity check predicate and a varargs of value suppliers that will be computed in the given order